# Oracle SQL: repeating a process for multiple tables

Tags: sql, loops, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11g. I would like to 'loop' this code through multiple tables t1 is already there, but I need to do this for 4 tables (t1,t2,t3, and t4):

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE t1';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE t1';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  IF SQLCODE !=-942 THEN
    RAISE;
  END IF;
END;
```

I can change this manually, but the code then swells and I would really like to control it just once.:-) Also the tables may not be sequentially labelled.  Thank you in advance.

Kate

Comment: In SQL reusage is not that important than in OOP development. Use Dynamic SQL if you  really have no oher choice.

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop where you select the table names from dual. You could also have a table containing the names and select from this.

```
BEGIN
 for t in 
   (
     select 't1' as table_name from dual 
     union all 
     select 't2' as table_name from dual 
     union all 
     select 't3' as table_name from dual 
     union all 
     select 't4' as table_name from dual 
    )
  loop
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || t.table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || t.table_name;
  end loop;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  IF SQLCODE !=-942 THEN
    RAISE;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `truncate` a table before you drop it, so the `drop table` is sufficient. Additionally, I'd add the `purge` modifier so that it doesn't clutter the recycle bin.

```
begin
  for t in (select table_name from user_tables
             where regexp_like(table_name, '^T[1-4]$')) loop

     execute immediate 'drop table ' || t.table_name || ' purge';

  end loop;
end;
/
```

Of course, you can drop the table in a specific procedure:

```
declare
   procedure drop_table(t in varchar2) is begin
     execute immediate 'drop table ' || t || ' purge';
   exception when others then
      if sqlcode != -942 then
         raise;
      end if;
   end drop_table;

begin
   drop_table('T1');
   drop_table('T2');
   drop_table('T3');
   drop_table('T4');
end;
/
```